# I keep getting "Not found. Authentication passthru" for Facebook connect login with Devise - Need debug advice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise

I've seen a couple people ask a similar question, but I really need advice on how to debug this issue. I'm trying to setup facebook connect using Devise using the article here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Every time I click on the login with facebook link, I get the blank page that just says: Not found. Authentication passthru. Clearly, there is no JavaScript/ajax setup on the prior page to pull up the facebook login screen.

I know this can work on my system, as I made a blank project with the exact same code from the link above and it works. Of course, my project is much bigger with lots of code, so I'm trying to figure out what in my project is causing this not to fire.

Any help on how to debug is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your configuration and controller code.

Answer (score 1):

This is the #passthru code from the devise source.

```
def passthru
    render :status => 404, :text => "Not found. Authentication passthru."
end
```

Which means that devise is unable to recognize your facebook callback. Make sure you setup up your callback controller properly or post your user controller code.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error. I was missing the Facebook callback controller (app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb):

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  # ...

  def facebook
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {
        @user = User.find_for_facebook(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

        if @user.persisted?
          sign_in_and_redirect @user
          set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
        else
          session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
          redirect_to new_user_registration_url
        end
      }
    end
  end
end
```

This code references the method "find_for_facebook" in my user model (app/models/user.rb):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # ...

  def self.find_for_facebook(auth_hash)
    user = User.where(:email => auth_hash.info["email"]).first

    unless user
      user = User.create(
        username: auth_hash.info["nickname"],
        email: auth_hash.info["email"],
        password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20])
    end

    user.provider = auth_hash["provider"]
    user.uid = auth_hash["uid"]
    user
  end
end
```

Make sure to restart your development server so all the changes get picked up.